# SQL group by equivalent in map-reduce

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Most of the queries I run have this format:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),A.a1 FROM A WHERE A.a2='x' GROUP BY A.a1
```

And the `A` table is an hdfs folder with csv files in it.

Since `hive` is ridiculously slow, how can I implement this query in `map-reduce` ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't your question as hive internally does map-reduce for you. Can you elaborate what exactly are you looking for ??

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL query can be mapped to the HelloWorld equivalent of MapReduce: WordCount.

I doubt that a custom implementation can do it much faster than Hive (which compiles to MapReduce), but here is how to do it:

- TextInputFormat -> `(pos, line)`
- `(pos, line)` -> `Mapper`: parse / tokenize line, extract `a1` and `a2`, filter on `a2='x'`) -> `(a1, count=1)`
- `(a1, count)` -> `Reducer`: Sum all `count` fields -> `(a1, sum)`
- `(a1, sum)` -> some OutputFormat

Hadoop will automatically take care of the `GroupBy` because the Mapper sets `a1` as key field.

Don't forget to set the Reducer also as Combiner to enable local pre-aggregation.

If you are looking for faster execution, you should consider another file format (Parquet, ORC) and another engine (Hive-on-Tez, Apache Flink, Apache Spark, or even a specialized engine for structured data like Apache Drill, Impala, Apache Kylin, Presto, ...). The best choice depends among other things on the size of your data, the execution time requirements (sub-second, < 1 min, ...), and what kind of other use-cases you would like to handle.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [hadoop streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) instead of hive,

Yet I can't guarantee it would be much faster

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-*.jar -D -jobconf stream.non.zero.exit.is.failure=false –mapper ‘grep {p}’ –reducer ’wc -l’ –input {d} –output tmp
hadoop fs -getmerge tmp {d}
hadoop fs –rmr tmp
```

replace `{d}` with your input dir, and `{p}` with a regex pattern that catches your condition

Answer (score 1):

May the below steps would give you the idea about this,

From **Mapper** ,

1. Split the line with comma delimiter
2. check if a2 = x and confirm
3. write a1 as key and int 1 as value

From **Reducer**,

1. iterate over all values of the given key
2. do sum of all 1's of the key
3. after loop , reuse the same key object as key and sum as value.

Please go through the Summarization patterns from the **Mapreduce design patterns** book by Donald Miner.